# Building a structure/object in a place other than the constructor

Tags: c#, java, ooad

I have different types of objects representing the same business entity.
`UIObject`, `PowershellObject`, `DevCodeModelObject`, `WMIObject` all are different representation to the same entity.

So say if the entity is `Animal` then I have `AnimalUIObject`, `AnimalPSObject`, `AnimalModelObject`, `AnimalWMIObject`, etc.

Now the implementations of `AnimalUIObject`, `AnimalPSObject`, `AnimalModelObject` are all in separate assemblies.

Now my scenario is I want to verify the contents of business entity `Animal` irrespective of the assembly it came from. So I created a `GenericAnimal` class to represent the `Animal` entity.

Now in `GenericAnimal` I added the following constructors:

```
GenericAnimal(AnimalUIObject)
GenericAnimal(AnimalPSObject)
GenericAnimal(AnimalModelObject)
```

Basically I made `GenericAnimal` depend on all the underlying assemblies so that while verifying I deal with this abstraction.

Now the other approach to do this is have `GenericAnimal` with an empty constructor
an allow these underlying assemblies to have a `Transform()` method which would build the `GenericAnimal`.

Both approaches have some pros and cons:

The 1st approach:
Pros: All construction logic is in one place in one class `GenericAnimal`
Cons: `GenericAnimal` class must be touched every-time there is a new representation form.

The 2nd approach:
Pros: construction responsibility is delegated to the underlying assembly.
Cons: As construction logic is spread accross assemblies, tomorrow if I need to add a property `X` in `GenericAnimal` then I have to touch all the assemblies to change the `Transform` method.

Which approach looks better ?
or Which would you consider a lesser evil ?
Is there any alternative way better than the above two ?

Just to elaborate further based on the comments i received.
I dont have the luxury the modify the structure of underlying objects, ie i cant change AnimalUIObject AnimalPSObject etc. The GenericAnimal is a construct introduced just for validation purposes by me.

Comment: I notice .NET terminology - why the Java tag?

Comment: Although the terminology is .Net the question really is language independent.

Comment: I think you could really use something better than `Animal` as an example here.

Comment: Ideally all objects should implement the same interface.  If you have the power to change them all, I'd consider doing it.  Otherwise you should implement the necessary wrappers which do.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think both approaches are pretty "evil".

I think what you really need is to start with the `Animal` class as your core class, and make the rest of the classes wrapper classes that use the `Animal` class to hold the representation.  Validation is then performed against the Animal API.

Comment: + I also feel the exposed design seems backwards. You beat me to put it in words. :)

Comment: But I dont have the luxury to modify the underlying object structures. To elaborate We have multiple APIs from which we get these different type of objects. And We have wrapper assemblies for each of these entry points to get an Animal Entity. Now when i Get these objects before passing it to the validation layer i have to convert them to GenericAnimal.  My question was basically should this conversion be in the GenericAnimal Class constructor or as a Transform method in each of the Wrapper assembly ?

Comment: @VishalNaidu - I understand your question.  The correct solution is to modify the underlying object structure.  It is not a luxury ... it is a necessity (IMO).  If you can't do that, then the two solutions you proposed are (IMO) equally bad.  Both are going to result in duplicative code and more potential bugs.

Comment: The underlying code is production code. I cant touch that. The validation code which i would write will not be shipped. so the solution you proposed will be unacceptable. To add further, all these representations are from different clients like Powershell/UI they have their own entity representations, which i cannot break for validations.

Comment: So if you have to write evil (test) code because the production code is badly designed, do it.  But where I come from, it is a GOOD THING to fix badly designed production code.  "I can't touch it" is a sign that something is dysfunctional in your organization's (or client organization's) development processes.

Answer (score 0):

May be an opportunity for an abstract factory pattern ?

Comment: All these types cannot Extend / Contain GenericAnimal. GenericAnimal is a construct introduced later for validation purpose only, all the multiple implementations exist without GenericAnimal.

Answer (score 0):

> I have different types of objects representing the same business
>   entity. UIObject, PowershellObject, DevCodeModelObject, WMIObject all
>   are different representation to the same entity.

Take a look to [Design Patterns](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Software_design_pattern) in general and in particular to [Structural Pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Structural_pattern).

In my understanding the [Decorator Pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decorator_pattern) would be useful:

> The decorator pattern can be used to extend (decorate) the
>   functionality of a certain object at run-time, independently of other
>   instances of the same class, provided some groundwork is done at
>   design time. This is achieved by designing a new decorator class that
>   wraps the original class

So it should be the first approach but w/o the cons:

The GenericAnimal class will have a constructor:

```
GenericAnimal(AnimalObject)
```

With `AnimalObject` either an interface or abstract class.

> Cons: GenericAnimal class must be touched every-time there is a new
>   representation form.

If you add another representation form make it implements or extends `AnimalObject`.